# How to bulid Application template Vue

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue and to ES6
And I did the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import $ from 'jquery'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
var App = {};
App.template = `
<main-menu></main-menu>
<router-view></router-view>`;

 const  header = Vue.component('main-menu', require('./components/app/header.vue'));
 const  facebook = Vue.component('facebook-gif', require('./components/facebook.vue'));

 const router = new VueRouter({
 routes: [
     {
        path: '/',
     },
     {
        path: '/facebook',
        component: {
            facebook: facebook
        }
     }
   ]
 });

App.app = new Vue({
    router,
    render (h) {
        return h(`div`, App.template)
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

But what it's nothing render , I just see the `main-menu` and `router-view` tags in my broswer...

And when I edit my html and put there this:

```
<div id="app">
     <main-menu></main-menu>
     <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

I get this error when I'm trying to enter the facebook route:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

and the facebook template is wrapped with `template` tag and it's inside a vue file
`facebook.vue`

```
 <template>
    <div>
    dsfsdsfdsf
        <div v-if="showLogin">
            <button v-on:click="login">Log In With Facebook</button>
            <span v-if="error">{{ error }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showLogin: true,
            error:null,
        }
    },
    methods() {
        return {
            login() {

            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But the main-menu component is render...

What is the problem?

**EDIT**
I downloaded the example like wostex said
I create an `App.vue` file contain:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <main-menu></main-menu>
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

I edit my html file to contain

I added in app.js

```
 import App from './components/App.vue'
 const v = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    render: h => h(App)

 });
```

and my html file contain:

```
 <div id="app"></div>
```

and I get this error:

```
 vue.common.js:436 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or       render function not defined.

  found in

 ---> <Anonymous>
   <App> at        /opt/lampp/htdocs/gif/resources/assets/js/components/App.vue
     <Root>
```

it happens because the facebook component, when I'm in the main page I don't see the error, only when I enter the facebook route

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple as a setup example.

Comment: @wostex look on my edit please

Answer (score 0):

It seems your first set up was failing because of what build you we're using. For eg:

```
App.app = new Vue({
    router,
    render (h) {
        return h(`div`, App.template) // this part can be roughly
        // translated to `return h(`div`, 
        // `<one-component></one-component>
        //  <router-view></router-view>`)` and I believe 
        // this failed due to the fact that when you pass 
        // template string to the render method it needs to 
        // be compiled and your setup didn't account for that. 
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Your other set up ( as per suggestion of @wostex ) is much better but I think that here you are missing `.$mount('#app')` at the end of your Vue initialization. So:

```
const v = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Laracasts in Jeffry tutorial about Vue
He did there like that:

```
    const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
        },
        {
            path: '/facebook',
            component:  require('./components/facebook.vue')

        }
      ]
    });
```

and it work's

So thanks every one that tried to help me